# How to cast object to another type and remove unneeded fields in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following code:

```
interface A {
    a: number;
}

interface B extends A {
    b: number;
}

const b: B = {a: 1, b: 5};
const a: A = b as A;
```

Now the variable `a` has type `A`, but it still contains `b` inside of it. Sometimes it is undesirable - I'd like to be sure that, if I have a variable of type `A`, it has the exact fields of type `A`. I was wondering, whether TypeScript has some kind of a "hard cast" which would remove any unneeded fields when converting between types.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't do *any* casting or conversion. Also it's structurally typed, so *"this thing isn't X because it has extra fields"* doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no casting in TypeScript because that's not how TypeScript works. TS is a type layer on top of JS. When you assign a type in TS you don't set a type, you *annotate* that the given expression is of a certain type. When the TS code is transpiled to JS, all type information is stripped.

Or in other words: the type system is JS, with TS you just announce that a variable is of a certain type. More often than never it happens that you assign the wrong type at design time and get suprised during debug that the variable has a completely different type than expected.

If you want to be sure that a property is removed from an object, you need to go the JS way (and - if necessary - annotate the result with TS). Check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object) to see how to remove properties from an object.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript won't do this for you, because it's not his job.

```js
interface A {
    a: number;
}

interface B extends A {
    b: number;
}

const b: B = {a: 1, b: 5};
const a: A = b as A; // you want to remove a.b
```

Using the ellipsis

```js
const {a, ...otherProperties} = b; // extract the property `a` and keep the other properties in `otherProperties`
```

Or just delete "a", but avoid deleting, it's imperative and TS won't understand it, it is also slower to handle deleted properties for the vm

```js
delete a.b;
```

Or using lodash, you can pick the properties you want

```js
const a = _.pick(b, ["a"]); // pick only a
```

Or omit a property still using lodash

```
const a = _.pick(b, ["b"]); // omit b
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmRAFcBbAI2gG4sBfLLUSWRFAIWQgA9IQATAM5pMOPBSKlKNeowQB7EILDIJyTgF5MhZAEYANKqIBWOrSwKlKjHEMA6B-LAALaAAUo8gA7QwwCIJ0yFoU5k6uUB7evv6C1HgA9AnBmEbIpshY4e6ePlB+AXahyEkpxlkuOdH5sXZw8aVaJAIQMKAQ-Ib88gHETlzcwMqAZARY9XgTk5ONeoZUCHAkgigAnvIkyPyt7fzIAAZwe-jCFHXIisgANu16ulhAA)

Answer (score 0):

I originally didn't plan on answering, but the reason I chose to answer because I feel like deleting the data in the original object might not always be a good idea.

Instead I think it's better to create a new variable and copy the data (without the unneeded properties) to the new variable.

I my case, I wanted to cast my register form into login information (email & password) and other information (on how the found the website).

The following solution is fairly easy to use (in various situations) and easily expandible.

```
export class HowFoundWas {
  howFoundWas: foundWasMedia;
  referrerdBy?: string;
  otherSocialMedia?: string;
  referredBySocialMedia?: string;
  otherMedia?: string;

  constructor(howFoundWas: any) {
    [
      "howFoundWas",
      "referrerdBy",
      "otherSocialMedia",
      "referredBySocialMedia",
      "otherMedia",
    ].forEach((prop) => {
      this[prop] = howFoundWas[prop];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It's creative but a little messy, in general, a solution that doesn't require changing the classes is usually preferred.