# Generic function to remove unwanted properties from object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

(It's a similar question as [How to cast object to another type and remove unneeded fields in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378612/how-to-cast-object-to-another-type-and-remove-unneeded-fields-in-typescript), I want to reframe it to see if I can get some light on the matter, not necessarily related to type casting)

I have an `any` object, and I need to select only the properties existing in an interface I have, thus removing the unwanted properties from the `any` object.

Let's say I have the interfaces:

```js
interface Address {
  street: string;
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  address: Address;
}
```

and I receive the object:

```js
const obj: any = {
  id: 123,
  name: 'Name Surname',
  address: {
    number: 456,
    street: 'Long street'
}};
```

So I need to turn `obj` into a `personObj`, excluding the fields not present in `Person` (which would be `id` and `address.number`.

I already know it doesn't work to make a simple casting operation like the following:

```js
const personObj = obj as Person; // does nothing
```

as it doesn't remove the unwanted properties.

What I've been doing is:

```js
function convert(obj: Person): Person => {
  return {
    name: obj.name,
    address: {
      street: obj.address.street
}}};
```

But as my app grows with a couple of APIs, and I needed to do this with a couple of different interfaces, I wanted to create a generic function to solve this problem.

**Motivation**: I have an app that calls an API and stores the response to a cache. The API response is an object with lots of properties, and as I need to store the minimum data to the cache, I need to remove the unwanted properties, or select the wanted properties from the API response.

Comment: [_.pick](https://lodash.com/docs/#pick)?

Comment: @JaredSmith this lodash function sure helps to make one step towards my goal, but I still have to manually add the parameters' names. I'm looking for smth more generic. Tnx for your idea, tho! It hadn't crossed me yet

Comment: There are two possibilities here: either you are trying to exclude properties of an object at runtime based on the properties in a Typescript interface which only exists at compile-time (which will never work for precisely that reason) or I don't understand what you're after (sorry if that's the case). I think _.pick is probably the most convenient thing to use even if it doesn't get you as far as you want.